# XPathMessageQuery sm:body() expression

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation

We are trying to write some send receive activities in code in a xamlx service workflow and having some issues correlating message back to persisted instances.
The errror always comes up as 'A correlation query yielded an empty result set', so we started looking at our xpath expression and the message that is coming in.

Every xpath expression that i have seen contains something like

```
sm:body()/xg0:AddItemMessage/xg0:CartId
```

now i dont think sm:body() is an xpath expression ( rest of it makes sense with namespaces)

can someone point out what sm:body() function is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a XPATH function defined inside the .NET framework which you can reuse as a shorthand for longer XPATH expressions.

The `body()` function returns a node set containing just the node body which would be equivalent to something like `/s11:Envelope/s11:Body` or `/s12:Envelope/s12:Body`.

For a list of functions defined by the .NET Framework and which you can reuse you can reference the following blog post:

[ServiceModel XPath Functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/routingrules/archive/2010/05/05/servicemodel-xpath-functions.aspx)